# How do I start an external process using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

### **FINAL EDIT: The code I've written below works, so disregard everything I've written. It seems that when I copied my input text file to the build directory, the file was somehow corrupted in process, which caused my external executable "prog" to break. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks to all of you who tried to help!**

I've just started messing around with Qt and have a project called test_tiny. In the build folder of my project (where executable test_tiny is located), I have moved another little C++ executable called "prog" which reads from a file, does its thing, and outputs to a different file. The input file is also in the build directory.

I also have a window with a couple of text boxes and a few buttons. I would like to run my external program "prog" by pressing one of these buttons. This is what I've got so far:

```
void MainWindow::load2() {
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start("./prog");
    qDebug() << process->exitCode();
    ui->textBrowser_2->clear();
    ui->textBrowser_2->insertPlainText(read(":/File/out.txt"));
}
```

The second part works just fine - it reads from the out.txt file and loads it into the text browser. However, my process doesn't seem to run, and exitCode() always returns zero (I have changed it to 100 in "prog").

From what I've understood, the QProcess' working directory (unless otherwise specified) is set to its build folder, so calling `process->start("./prog");` should work, but it doesn't. I've also tried calling it by referencing a `QResource` as well as giving the full path, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I'm using Qt Creator 2.81 based on Qt 5.1.1 running on x64 Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the executable "prog" only parses a few lines of text and outputs them to a file, which is then read and output to a text box. The external program "prog" doesn't actually seem to run, and I've already tried using `process->waitForFinished()`.

Comment: Not a Qt developer, but a lot of `Process` classes (in various languages) don't wait for the return code. It's up to you to call something like `process->waitForExit()`. *Then* the return code is available.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait till the process is finished before you check the exit code.  You can wait by using the finised() signal or waitForFinished(). After waitForFinished succeeds or the finished signal is emitted it is safe to check the exit code. I almost always will use the finshed signal. However you should also make sure that the process started in the first place. Using the error() signal is how I detect if there is a problem starting the process. QProcess will emit this with a code describing the error. QProcess::FailedToStart will tell you that your application did not start in the first place.

Comment: Maybe you should read your own answer once after (or, better: before) posting.

Comment: The external process I'm trying to run doesn't actually run in the first place - this is my problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the program prog is in the current working folder of your application?

Comment: If prog is in the current working folder of your application are you sure it is marked as executable in linux?

Comment: BTW, QDir::current() should return whatever the current working folder is in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Are you on the correct path? while debugging using a full path, it make life easier.
2. You need to call QProcess::waitForFinished(LARGE_TIME) or connect to the finished() signal before you can check the error (the app starts asynchronously).